# "During years 2017-2019" vs. "During the years 2017-2019"

Tags: articles, definite-article

> 1. "During years 2017-2019, he appeared four times on the podcast."
>
> or
>
> 2. "During the years 2017-2019, he appeared four times on the podcast"

Are both of them correct? If not, which of them and why?
I was not able to find anything on the Web/SE that would provide me with the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"During years 2017-2019" and "During the years 2017-2019" both sound unnatural since "years" is discrete, not continuous, and you are describing a period rather than naming the specific years. (You could say "during the years 2017, 2018 and 2019").

It would be more natural to say "During the period from 2017 to 2019" or, more simply, "from 2017 to 2019".

Comment: I agree, there are more natural-sounding phrases. I noticed that two of out of the three proposed by you alternative phrases contain a definite article.